# limit reward button press to once an hour

Tags: java, android, timer, counter, limit

I have a reward advert system setup within my app. at the moment every time I press my reward button a reward advert shows. But I want to limit this to one click every hour.

this is my button onclick which is situated within my advert loaded method. I've done it this way as on some devices which have a slow internet connection the ad wasn't loading before people were pressing the button.

```
 @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(Competition.this, "Advert loaded please click the Reward button to continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncomp_ok);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showRewardedVideo();
                }
            });

        }
```

I Also have a Firebase Database connected to my app. this counts the times the advert is watched to the end.

```
 ref.child("Reward").child(Userid).child("screenname").setValue(Username);
    ref.child("Reward").child(Userid).child("watched").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

            if (mutableData.getValue() == null) {
                mutableData.setValue(1);
            } else {
                int count = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
                mutableData.setValue(count + 1);
            }
            ;

            return Transaction.success(mutableData);


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the last time they clicked and make sure an hour has passed before calling showRecordedVideo().  lastClickTime can be stored in the db or sharedpreferences.

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    static int ONEHOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    Toast.makeText(Competition.this, "Advert loaded please click the Reward button to continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncomp_ok);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= lastClickTime + ONEHOUR) {
                showRewardedVideo();
            }
        }
    });
}
```